# Does the structure of a match query affect the server

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing some code to generate queries and I wondered if there was any one way of generating the queries that was kinder to the server.

So this query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Text": {
              "query": "Scooby Shaggy corridor",
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "operator": "AND"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

is logically equivalent to this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Text": {
              "query": "Scooby",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Text": {
              "query": "Shaggy",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Text": {
              "query": "corridor",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but is either one easier for the server to process?
Or does it make no difference?

I realise this is a trivial example but could it make a difference with more complex queries?

If someone who knows a bit about how ElasticSearch behaves under the hood could make an observation I'd be grateful.

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch will rewrite itself your multi-term match query to the logical equivalent.  see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-boolean) for more details.

> The match query is of type boolean. It means that the text provided is
>   analyzed and the analysis process constructs a boolean query from the
>   provided text.

But you should keep the multi-term match query and let elasticsearch do the job. Its more maintainable and you can control the rewriting thanks to the `rewrite` parameter ( see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html) )

Comment: Thanks, Pierre. The funny thing is I had read the page you directed me to but had missed the significance of the phrase you highlighted.